# Using jQuery inside image tag within .html() method

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am trying to setup a page which contains an HTML table. You would be able to click on any row on the table to pull up a modal with a different image. The image URLs will be stored as data-ids in the  tags as I must do all of this in a browser and have no sever to make calls to.

I have the following code to setup my modal. By itself, $(this).data('chi') gets the data-chi id which is the image url. How do I use that within the HTML inside the .html() jQuery method? I tried various escapes but cannot figure it out.

```
$('#orderDetails').html($("<b>  Order Id selected: <img src=\'\$(this).data('chi')\' alt=\"Smiley face\">" + '</b>'));

$('#orderModal').modal('show');
```

Link to JSFiddle - https://jsfiddle.net/rHHmz/171/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the best way is saving the `data-chi` attribute in a variable first, and then you can use it in string concatenation, like:

```
var chi = $(this).data('chi');
$('#orderDetails').html($("<b>  Order Id selected: <img src='"+chi+"' alt=\"Smiley face\">" + '</b>'));
```

[**DEMO**](https://jsfiddle.net/rHHmz/172/)

Answer (score 1):

Use string concatenation

```js
$(function() {
  var $orderModal = $('#orderModal').modal({
    keyboard: true,
    backdrop: "static",
    show: false,
  });

  $('.table-striped tr[data-id]').on('click', function() {

    $orderModal.html('<b>  Order Id selected: <img src="' + $(this).data('chi') + '" alt="Smiley face "></b>');
    $orderModal.modal('show');

  });

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/twitter-bootstrap/2.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/twitter-bootstrap/2.3.1/css/bootstrap-combined.min.css" />

<h1>Orders</h1>
<table class="table table-striped">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>ID</th>
      <th>Customer</th>
      <th>Status</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr data-id="1" data-chi="//placehold.it/64X64&text=1">
      <td>1</td>
      <td>24234234</td>
      <td>A</td>
    </tr>
    <tr data-id="2" data-chi="//placehold.it/64X64&text=2">
      <td>2</td>
      <td>24234234</td>
      <td>A</td>
    </tr>
    <tr data-id="3" data-chi="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/thumb/6/6e/JMPlogo.png/250px-JMPlogo.png" data-hello="bye">
      <td>3</td>
      <td>24234234</td>
      <td>A</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
<div id="orderModal" class="modal hide fade" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="orderModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
  <div class="modal-header">
    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">x</button>
    <h3>Order</h3>

  </div>
  <div id="orderDetails" class="modal-body"></div>
  <div id="orderItems" class="modal-body"></div>
  <div class="modal-footer">
    <button class="btn" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">Close</button>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Cleaned up in your JSFiddle so the JS now reads:

```
$(function () {
    $('#orderModal').modal({
        keyboard: true,
        backdrop: "static",
        show: false,
    });

    $(".table-striped").find('tr[data-id]').on('click', function (e) {
        $('#orderDetails').html("<b>  Order Id selected: <img src=\"" + $(e.target).parent().data('chi') + "\" alt=\"Smiley face\"></b>");
        $('#orderModal').modal('show');
    });
});
```

Basically, to get at what triggered the event, you have to pass the event object (`e` above) into the callback and then look around in the dom from where it was triggered. In this case, it's up to the row, since users will be clicking on a given `<td>` in the table, and the `<tr>` with the `data-id` attribute is its parent.